# Promise chain with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I'm a freshman in javascript, and now learning the Promise part.

Below I've been trying to write a promise chain with setTimeout, and expect it to print "first result" after 2 seconds, and print "second result" after another 2 seconds. However, it prints "first result" and "second result" at the same time.

Can anyone tell me where did I make a mistake?

```
var doSomething = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        resolve('first result');  
    },2000); 
});

var doSomethingElse = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve('second result');  
    },2000); 
});

doSomething
    .then(function(result){
    console.log("This is the "+result); 
    return doSomethingElse;
    })
    .then(function(result){
        console.log("This is the "+result);
});
```

============================

**EDIT**:
So when I write promise as below, the executor function(setTimeout) starts counting immediately, and become resolved after 2 seconds.

```
var doSomething = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){   // starts counting here
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        resolve('first result');  
    },2000); 
});
```

However, if I wrap the promise inside a function as below, the executor function (setTimeout) starts counting **only after** I call the function. Is this correct?

```
function doSomething(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('first result');
        },2000);
    })
}
doSomething(); // starts counting here
```

Comment: You're starting both promises at the same time. You're just chaining them so their responses are printed in a defined order. If you want to start the second promise after the first resolves, you need to put that `new Promise` into the `.then()` of the first.

Comment: Questions in the Edit: Yes & Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a promise and assigning it to `doSomething`. The first timer starts counting down.

Then you **immediately** create another promise and assign it to `doSomethingElse`. The second timer starts counting down.

---

Create the second promise **after** the first one has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the `doSomething` promise and the `doSomethingElse` promise are created in very quick succession and will resolve in very quick succession aout 2 seconds later.

There's nothing in the code to cause the two processes to be sequential. For that, you would need to ensure that `doSomethingElse` starts its 2 seconds after `doSomething` had completed.

There's a number of ways you can organise the code to make this happen.

For example, you could write the `new Promise(...)` expressions directly into your Promise chain without making any assignments:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('first result');
    }, 2000);
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('second result');
        }, 2000);
    });
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result);
});
```

Or, you could write `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` as functions:

```js
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('first result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
function doSomethingElse() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('second result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}

doSomething()
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result); 
    return doSomethingElse();
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result);
});
```

Or, you could write a single `doSomething()` function and call it twice:

```js
function doSomething(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(value);
        },2000);
    });
}

doSomething('first result')
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result); 
    return doSomething('second result');
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result);
});
```

Or, going back to `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` as separate functions, you could add a third `logResult()` function to do the logging:

```js
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('first result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
function doSomethingElse() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('second result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
function logResult(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result); 
}

doSomething()
.then(function(result) {
    logResult(result);
    return doSomethingElse();
})
.then(function(result) {
    logResult(result);
});
```

A nice feature of the previous example is that the Promise chain will simplify as follows:

```js
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('first result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
function doSomethingElse() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('second result');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
function logResult(result) {
    console.log("This is the " + result); 
}

doSomething()
.then(logResult)
.then(doSomethingElse)
.then(logResult);
```

As you can see, there's no unique solution.